# An error has occurred during web site deployment - Azure with Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, flask

I have a small project on azure that runs with flask. 
I finished setting most of the environment in which I plan to develop this project (flask-resftul package and requests package, however these are not added into the requirements.txt and I decided to do a `pip freeze` to check both requests and flask-resftul versions).

I decided to copy both of them into the requirements.txt and in my local machine it runs fine. However, once I do the push to github and it syncs with azure I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\63.60712.2926\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

The requirements.txt file looks like this:

```
Flask<1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.6
requests==2.18.3
```

The first commit was done as soon as the project was finished being setup in my local machine. It ran fine on azure and the demo page displayed properly. However, as soon as I updated the requirements.txt file like I mentioned and showed above, the deployment error started to show on the logs.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I erased the .skipPythonDeployment file so that it could run the requirements.txt file and install any new dependency needed.

Any idea how to solve this issue will greatly be appreciated.